# Rstudio Server Highchart Opens New Tab

Tags: highcharts, rstudio

I have an unusual issue (can't find anything on SO or Google).

I have installed Rstudio on the amazon cloud. When I try to run any code to produce a highchart the instance opens a blank tab.

Here is the simple code I am using...

```
library(highcharter)
md <- (1:10)
hchart(md)
```

The first two lines run fine, but when I run the third line a new tab opens with the URL...

http://my.cloud.url:8787/file_show?path=%2Ftmp%2FRtmpUwu8Vb%2Fviewhtml777930f3f5e2%2Findex.html

Has anyone seen this issue before / know what is happening or how to resolve?

Thanks

Mike

Comment: Seems that your website is not available (server is down)

Comment: Hi, this happend only with highcharter? Have you tried with other htmlwidgets?